# how to use umm al qura calendar in sharepoint datetime control?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

how to use umm al qura calendar in sharepoint datetime control ?

any ideas please ???

EDIT: i found some articles about this problem , they are talking about "Hooking" , i have to hooking the dll to change return type of a method in runtime

i don't have enough knowledge about hooking , any ideas or resources please ??

Answer (score 1):

follow the technet article below this will help you out but currently we get hijri support with OOTB features not umm al qura

http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2009/12/02/global-features-in-windows-sharepoint-foundation-2010.aspx

If you are willing to create your own calendar type you can take help from following codeplex project 
http://persiansharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/27417

Answer (score 1):

Selam!

check this link:

http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2008/09/persian-calendar-for-sharepoint-2007.html
and also this treads that seems to be talking about the same issue's:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/10592442-023a-4c15-b0a9-834a06959705/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/b5d22a6d-3940-41ab-a69b-643e131c24b5/

You can also check these links:
http://www.sharepointsolutions.ir/fa-us/products/Pages/Calandar.aspx

http://www.codeplex.com/sharepoint2007farsi

aslo if you need technical resources in Persian Languege about SharePoint, Persian Blogs, Screen Casts, Technical Documents, Demonstrations and so on.. take a look here:

http://www.sharepointsolutions.ir/fa-us/resources/Pages/default.aspx

Good luck from Sweden :)